# Winter Bash 2014 - Time to wear hats again?

Tags: discussion

Remember last year's [Winter Bash 2013](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) when we could discover and wear hats all over the site during the season's holidays? Now a new winter approaches, and we will have the opportunity to participate in the Winter Bash 2014 too.

During the seasons (from 15 December 2014 to 4 January 2015) we will be able to discover and wear funny hats by using our site in special ways, such as voting, posting on meta, editing posts to be better, chatting, and more (there may be secret hats again). After 4 January all will be back to normal.

Of course there also will be a "I hate hats" option for any user who does not want to wear a hat.

Should we as a community participate? Please vote below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes

let's wear hats again.

Comment: This is obviously the only correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Hmm...

... I don't care about hats.

Comment: Yeah, don't care about hates. :)

Answer (score 1):

**Why not?**

I have no idea what you are talking about, but I am curiuos and it sounds like fun.

Comment: Good point - I copied a link to Winter Bash 2013 to the question.

Answer (score 0):

## No

I hate to see hats all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Should be automatically turned on every year without discussion site wide and eligleble for personal turn off per user without disturbing interviews every year.